# How to send checkbox value: either true or false, through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to send the value of my checkbox to database using ajax. Through some searching in internet, I somehow managed to get this far.This is what I have been using. What changes do I need to make on json2.stringify for it to correctly send my values.

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="txtCategoryIsPaid" name="cateogryIsPaid" value="Paid">Yes<br>
```

Javascript:

```
AddCategory: function () {                
            BusinessManagement.config.method = "AddBusinessCategory";
            BusinessManagement.config.url = BusinessManagement.config.baseURL + BusinessManagement.config.method;
            BusinessManagement.config.data = JSON2.stringify({

                CategoryIsPaid: $('#txtCategoryIsPaid :checked').val(),

            });
            BusinessManagement.config.ajaxCallMode = 0;
            BusinessManagement.ajaxCall(BusinessManagement.config);
```

Comment: `$('#txtCategoryIsPaid').is(':checked')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.prop('checked')` attribute

```
<HTML>
<input type="checkbox" id="txtCategoryIsPaid" name="cateogryIsPaid" value="Paid">Yes<br>

Javascript
AddCategory: function () {                
            BusinessManagement.config.method = "AddBusinessCategory";
            BusinessManagement.config.url = BusinessManagement.config.baseURL + BusinessManagement.config.method;
            BusinessManagement.config.data = JSON2.stringify({

                CategoryIsPaid: $('#txtCategoryIsPaid').prop('checked') == true ? "true": "false",

            });
            BusinessManagement.config.ajaxCallMode = 0;
            BusinessManagement.ajaxCall(BusinessManagement.config);
```

Comment: thank you shubham.this solved my problem.

btw are you from nepal?also can u share some link that would solve some other similar problems for select and image types?

Comment: @BibekAryal What type of links are you looking for. btw I am not from nepal.

Comment: i still have to send the value of  html "select" and also filepath of "image". so i was wondering if there was a site with collective info on all of these?

Comment: @BibekAryal Kindly accept the answer if it helped you. It will be useful for others in future

Comment: i am sorry about that.its just that it worked so fast that, stackoverflow wouldnt allow me to accept answer for 2 minutes and i completely forgot about it later on

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri what is the need of ternary operation?

Comment: I used the ternary operation to send value as a string otherwise `$('#txtCategoryIsPaid').prop('checked') == true` returns value true as boolean.